# MySQL: Soft Delete post likes

Tags: mysql, database-design, best-practices

I have implemented a like/unlike features for posts in one of my projects. The like table is normalized and has a column `visible`. The schema is as follows:

```
Column      Type       Null    Default  Links to
id          int(11)     No           
user_id     int(11)     Yes     NULL    user  -> id      
post_id     int(11)     Yes     NULL    posts -> id      
visible     tinyint(1)  Yes     NULL         
created     datetime    No           
updated     datetime    No
```

What I'm doing currently is that when a user likes a post, I create a record and when he un-likes it, I just set the `visible` column to *false*. The count is calculated by `post_id` and `visible = true`. I did that to prevent excessive load on database when a user likes/unlikes a post.

My question is am I being paranoid in considering database performance so early (without much traffic) or is this among the best practices and I should continue with this?

Comment: Copy-on-delete to table_history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the balance between how often your data will be *accessed* vs how often your data will be *updated*.

Adding another condition on your `SELECT` just to display your content may well create more load than deleting rows in the infrequent occasion that a user un-likes. Note that you will need an index on `visible` to efficiently query against it.

Comment: Thank you. That's a very good point made regarding index on visible field.

Answer (score 3):

If `(post_id, user_id)` is unique, then jettison the `id` and make that pair the `PRIMARY KEY`.

I specifically suggest that order because I assume this query is frequently used?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE post_id = ?
      AND visible;
```

By having the PK *start* with `post_id`, you get the added efficiency of "clustering", thereby drastically reducing the I/O when this table eventually becomes so large that it can no longer be cached.

I chose not to include `visible` in any way because (1) it confuses the "uniqueness" requirement of the PK, and (2) the row would have to 'move' when `visible` changes.  This would be a bunch of overhead.  (OK, maybe that action is rare enough not to care.)

See also [my indexing cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

If you want to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the critical queries that hit the table.

Comment: Thanks Rick. I stumbled upon your cookbook earlier too and it very nicely explained the usage of index. There are currently indeces on post_id, user_id and visible columns. However, my question here is like asking whether I should hard delete the record when a user un-likes the post or just mark it as visible=false. Assuming he may want to like it again, I just have to modify a record. Does this make it more clear?

Comment: Let's look at frequency.  I suspect 97% of traffic is initial "likes", 2% is "unlikes", and 1% is "relikes".  For efficiency, optimize the "likes" and don't worry about the other cases.  For that, you may as well delete the row on an "unlike".

Comment: Right. I was leaning towards this approach too.